I need help smd ic mark " 125 A3" dfn-8

smd ic mark 125 A3,what is it？

Context is important. Could you zoom out a bit to show nearby components?

Could be ADA4692-2ACPZ (dual ampli ops) from Analog Devices.


The only picture I found was on aliexpress:

Don't forget to check dimensions.

that is right!You are very professional
